# Problem with django rest auth and react native

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am trying to make a login page with a react native frontend and a django-rest-auth backend, but when I send my request:

```
`login = () => {

fetch('http://myIp/rest-auth/login/', {
  method: 'POST',
  header: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: this.state.username,
    password: this.state.password,
  })
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((res) => {
  if (res.success === true) {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('user', res.user)
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')
  }
  else {
    alert(res.message)
  }
})
  }
}`
```

My backend returns:

> Unsupported Media Type

I only use django-rest-auth api endpoints. What is the problem ? Thank you for your help ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In above code you have used `header` instead `headers`. Please change your code like below.

```
login = () => {

fetch('http://myIp/rest-auth/login/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: this.state.username,
    password: this.state.password,
  })
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((res) => {
  if (res.success === true) {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('user', res.user)
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')
  }
  else {
    alert(res.message)
  }
})
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok now it recognizes the media type, but the react native app doesn't recognize the response ;/